# How can I share options parsing code within bash functions when using getopts?

Tags: bash, shell, dry, getopts

How can I clean up this options parsing code in a Bash function? It is copy-pasted into a number of functions that need to have a simple "-h" flag for printing usage. I would rather have a generic routine with the logical equivalent of

```
local prefix_opt1
local prefix_opt2
....
__handle_opts "usage message" "additional getopts flags" "prefix"
```

For example:

```
local foo_k
local foo_v
__handle_opts "Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]}" [-k key -v version] widget\nBuild a widget using the key and version." "k:v:" "foo_"

if [[ -z $foo_k ]] ; then
    foo_k="default value"
fi
.....
```

The functions are to be "sourced" in one's dot-bashrc file.

Here is what the code looks like (note: some of the functions do take options via flags):

```
function kitten_pet {

  local usage="Usage: ${FUNCNAME[0]} [-h] <kitten>\nPet the kitten."

  ################################################
  local help=0
  local error=0
  local OPTIND
  local opt
  while getopts ":h" opt "$@"
  do
    case $opt in

      h)
        echo -e "$usage"
        help=1
        break
        ;;

      \?)
        echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG"
        error=1
        break
        ;;
    esac
  done
  if [ $error -gt 0 ] || [ $help -gt 0 ] ; then
    return 1
  fi
  shift $((OPTIND-1))
  ################################################

  if [ $# -lt 1 ]
  then
    echo -e "$usage"
    return 1
  fi

  __kitten_pet "$1"
}
```

Ordinarily I would use something like node-commander or node-optimist and write the script in JavaScript (or perhaps Python) for scripting needs but I'm trying to make Bash work this time. But Bash is bashing me.

Comment: If you want to have some higher level options parsing, you probably should take a look at something like [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopts)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the generic option parser a list of options that the calling script will be managing.

For each option to be managed in the calling script, create a function called `option_X_parser`.  These option parser functions should accept an optional argument ($OPTARG), and should return 0 (success) or 1 (error).

The generic option parser should build a shell case statement using its generic options (e.g., "h", "n", and "v") as well as the supplied options from the calling program.  For those options that have an associate option parser function, the case statement should include invocations of the option parsers.

There should be a case statement for each configured option, which should invoke the user supplied functions, if defined, or be managed generically by setting global variables (.e.g., `opt_X`, where `X` is the specific option).

For example:

`__handle_options "$usage", 'hni:v'`

option_h_parser() { echo "$usage"; exit 1 ; }
option_n_parser() { norun=1 ; return 0 ; }
option_v_parser() { verbose=1 ; return 0 ; }
option_i_parser() { insert_at="$1" ; return 0 ; }   # invoke with argument

Basically, use implied function names, based on the option letter.

The return value of each option parser is examined by the generic option handler function.  Something like this:

`function_name="option_${opt}_parser"
if eval "$function_name $OPTARG" ; then
  # option is good
else
  error "'$opt' parser failed."
  exit 2
fi`